# Forward Looking stock Log Returns

Tags: r, logging, diff, stock

I am using the diff(log(x)) function but I need to calculate the forward looking returns on an xts data set, not returns based on historical data.

Basically when i calculate diff(log(x),lag=30) for a 30 day return, it eliminates the past 30 data points and starts calculating at day 30 it seems but I need it to start at day = 1, and compare this way:

price (day 1) to Price (day 30)
.
.
.
and so on

> diff(log(x), lag=-30)
>   tried this but gives error

is there perhaps something I am missing? Sorry I am a noob beginner and apologize if answer is obvious or am i missing how the diff log function operates

Comment: Not clear what you mean. It has to start at day 31 because for any earlier days there's no data for what happened 30 days before that. When you use lag = n the first comparison is of day 1 and day (n + 1), so choose whatever n you want with that in mind. For example, you say you want to compare days 1 and 30, so choose lag = 29. If you wish to subract day 30 from day 1 instead of the reverse (which is the default), just multiply the output off the diff function by -1.

Comment: I guess I what I am trying to say is that I want the first price to give a return by comparing it to look forward data 30 days in advance, and it drops off the last 30 days  of uncomputable data as opposed to the opposite. Right now it starts computing at day 30, and puts in 'NA' for the first 30 days

Comment: The behavior you are describing as what you want is what happens by default. The diff function does not add NAs for the first n items, just try diff(1:100, 30), there are no NAs. It would be good if you could show an example with real data. What your input is, and what you expect the output to be.

Comment: I think i see what is happening; if I use the library quantmod it gives me backward 30 day returns, but when i restarted r studio and did not load quantmod it works. Try it for yourself, use the function with and without quantmod

Comment: Ok, I am using this code for gold prices:                             library(quantmod)
getMetals('XAU', from=Sys.Date()-180)
diff(log(XAUUSD), lag=30)

Comment: Ignore my previous (now deleted) comment. The XAUUSD object's class is xts, so it has a different method (class-specific function) called when you do a diff on it, adding NAs at the start. However, the data after the NAs is the same. So if you don't want the NAs, you could just remove them

Comment: OK I understand, should I perform this on a list then?

Comment: If you put `as.numeric(XAUUSD)` inside the log instead of `XAUUSD` it will use the default method for diff (since the data is no longer an xts object)

Comment: ahh!! ok thank you, let me work on this some more; yes it worked!!!